# Calculator not shrinking to fit screen width

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-queries, calculator

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rokkitt:wght@600&display=swap');

* {
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Rokkitt', serif;
}

.calc {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  min-height: 95vh;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
}

.container {
  border: 10px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: rgb(77, 77, 77);
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 100px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(6, 80px);
  gap: 1px;
}

.display {
  border: 3px solid black;
  background-color: aqua;
  grid-column: 1/-1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: flex-end;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 3px;
  font-size: 3em;
}

button {
  margin: 1px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5%;
  font-size: 1.7em;
}

button:hover {
  filter: brightness(0.8);
}

.operand {
  background-color: rgb(211, 211, 201);
}

.decimal {
  background-color: rgb(211, 211, 201);
}

.operator {
  background-color: rgb(31, 142, 0);
}

.equal {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);
}

.clear {
  background-color: rgb(255, 51, 0);
}

#zero {
  grid-column: 1/3;
}

.equal {
  grid-column: 1/-2;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
    <title>Calculator</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <main class="calc">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="display">0</div>
        <button class="operand" value="7">7</button>
        <button class="operand" value="8">8</button>
        <button class="operand" value="9">9</button>
        <button class="clear">AC</button>
        <button class="operand" value="4">4</button>
        <button class="operand" value="5">5</button>
        <button class="operand" value="6">6</button>
        <button class="divide operator">/</button>
        <button class="operand" value="1">1</button>
        <button class="operand" value="2">2</button>
        <button class="operand" value="3">3</button>
        <button class="multiply operator">*</button>
        <button class="operand" id="zero" value="0">0</button>
        <button class="decimal" value=".">.</button>
        <button class="subtract operator">-</button>
        <button class="equal" value="=">=</button>
        <button class="add operator">+</button>
      </div>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've been trying for a while to make my calculator fit the screen but can't solve this problem.

When the screen size is less than 500px the calculator stays on the same width and does not fit the screen, i tried everything but not sure why it's not working.

this is the calculator: https://fedechini.github.io/Calculator/

any advice on how to fix that?

thanks in advance :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0):

use `minmax()` for your `.container` .

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(4, minmax(10px, 100px));
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rokkitt:wght@600&display=swap');

* {
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Rokkitt', serif;
}

.calc {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  min-height: 95vh;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
}

.container {
  border: 10px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: rgb(77, 77, 77);
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, minmax(10px, 100px));
  grid-template-rows: repeat(6, 80px);
  gap: 1px;
}

.display {
  border: 3px solid black;
  background-color: aqua;
  grid-column: 1/-1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: flex-end;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 3px;
  font-size: 3em;
}

button {
  margin: 1px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5%;
  font-size: 1.7em;
}

button:hover {
  filter: brightness(0.8);
}

.operand {
  background-color: rgb(211, 211, 201);
}

.decimal {
  background-color: rgb(211, 211, 201);
}

.operator {
  background-color: rgb(31, 142, 0);
}

.equal {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);
}

.clear {
  background-color: rgb(255, 51, 0);
}

#zero {
  grid-column: 1/3;
}

.equal {
  grid-column: 1/-2;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
    <title>Calculator</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <main class="calc">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="display">0</div>
        <button class="operand" value="7">7</button>
        <button class="operand" value="8">8</button>
        <button class="operand" value="9">9</button>
        <button class="clear">AC</button>
        <button class="operand" value="4">4</button>
        <button class="operand" value="5">5</button>
        <button class="operand" value="6">6</button>
        <button class="divide operator">/</button>
        <button class="operand" value="1">1</button>
        <button class="operand" value="2">2</button>
        <button class="operand" value="3">3</button>
        <button class="multiply operator">*</button>
        <button class="operand" id="zero" value="0">0</button>
        <button class="decimal" value=".">.</button>
        <button class="subtract operator">-</button>
        <button class="equal" value="=">=</button>
        <button class="add operator">+</button>
      </div>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could just set the width in percent while giving the container a `width` of 100% and a `max-width` so it won't grow much

```
.container {
    border: 10px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: rgb(77, 77, 77);
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 25%);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(6, 80px);
    gap: 1px;
    max-width: 500px;
    width: 100%;
}
```